# Im having a hard time trying to implent subscripts in python since im a bit newer

Tags: python, math

I have decided to start working on calculating values for An and Bn using a for loop however I cant seem to figure out where I should begin , or is it even neccesary to use subscripts , I cant use variable names since I want the value to sequence of n to increment by 1 in a loop. since the way to calculate An and Bn is to use the value for a0 and b0 and subtract n its very confusing to implemnt this in python since I want the value of n to increment , can anyone help , give me tips and guidance on how to approach this problem its been hard learning online. There is an Image of the equation[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/usZvg.png)

```
a0 = int(input('enter a value:')
b0 = int(input('enter a value:')
N = int(input('enter a value:')
n = 0

for i in range(0,N):
    n = n+1
    An=a(n-1)+10
    Bn =10*(b(n-1))
print(An,Bn) # For reference to see if it worked
```

Comment: no need of subscripts, use defined var names. this is a programming language not some math alternative

Comment: Looking at the equation, it seems you can define 2 recursive functions for a and b.

Answer (score 1):

While the other answer is technically correct, first of all, if you're going to be running a loop incrementing `n`, doing non-memoized recursion is first of all extremely inefficient as it's `O(n^2)` both in time and space, and second of all might blow your stack if `n` gets high enough (which it probably won't).

Instead, first of all, using some very elementary math, you can turn the formula of a_n into a direct formula with no need for the recursive definition - it's just `a_0 + 10n`. You can do the same for b_n which is just `b_0 * 10 ** n`.

Second of all, your syntax doesn't make any sense. `f(x)` is a function call in python so `b(n - 1)` means you are calling the function `b` on the argument `n - 1`. If you want indexed values, you should be using an array and doing `b[n - 1]` but in this case a) you can just use the closed form formula for each value of `n` and b) if you keep track of your current value of `a` and `b` starting with the input, you can just keep an accumulator for each and every time you loop just do `a += 10` and `b *= 10`.

Here's how I'd do it. Firstly, your brackets aren't balanced.

```py
a0 = int(input('enter a value:'))
b0 = int(input('enter a value:'))
N = int(input('enter a value:'))
```

Then, since your value of `n` is increasing each time, why loop over `i` and increase `n` each time and then ignore `i`? Just run a loop with `n`.

```py
a = a0
b = b0

for n in range(1, N + 1):
    a += 10
    b *= 10
    # do something with a and b, the current a_n and b_n values
```

Answer (score -1):

Assuming a and b are `>0` ints.

This is how you would do it for a.

```python
def nth_a(n):
    if n <= 0:
        return a0  # Base case
    return nth_a(n - 1) + 10
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TYsxCoAwEAR7X7FlDhES7ERfIiKCiaa5hCOCvj5GtHC62WHjlfbAbc6rdeC0z4ti6ioUfBnQD9CvPohNhzCMrn72vdDAEOoScxTPSY1vOAkuCE54hiy8WWU0TZRv)

For b do the same thing:

```python
def nth_b(n):
    if n < 2:
        return b0  # Base case
    return nth_b(n - 1) * 10
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TYsxCoAwEAR7X7FlThCMduJPREQx0TRnOCLo62MkFk43O6y/w35wG@NqLDjs06KYugIJlwb0aLK9iAmnMHTxk@@DCppQQtfRi@Oghhwugj0EFxxDZt6M0jWNFB8)

If you have noticed,  `an` and `bn` are defined in terms of themselves.